# Build/install llvm/clang with both 32 & 64-bit support libraries

Tags: clang, llvm, 32bit-64bit, libraries, building

My (built from source) llvm/clang install is able to create 32/64-bit executables fine, but when I created the installation it only produced 64-bit libraries (eg, libclang).

I've sifted through their documentation, looked through the configure help, etc.  As best I can tell my only option is to configure targeting a 32-bit host machine and do a separate installation.

---

I should probably add: there's 32/64-bit sanitizer libraries (eg, `libclang_rt.asan-i386.a`), it's the rest of the support libraries in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure LLVM and Clang with `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` i.e.:

```
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" \
CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" \
   ./configure --prefix=/prefix --enable-optimized --disable-assertions
```

Comment: Just FYI, this answer is no longer accurate with the cmake-based build. Unfortunately, I don't have a newer solution, either.